# java DateFormat - get default date pattern for India as DD-MM-YY

Tags: java, simpledateformat

The predominant date patteren for India is `DD-MM-YY`. 
I am trying to get the default date pattern for India using following code.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                            java.text.DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat)dateFormat).toPattern();
```

The pattern variable above has a value of "`d MMM, yyyy`". But I would like to get the date pattern as "`DD-MM-YY`".
How this can be achieved?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You don’t want `DD-MM-YY`. Pattern letters are case sensitive, and you want `dd-MM-yy`.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Asking because different Java versions may have different built-in localized formats.

Answer (score 2):

The gold-plated solution to your problem would be providing your own locale data for `en-IN` locale. On one hand it may be too much, and you can look for next-best solutions; on the other hand it’s doable if important. I haven’t seen custom date format data provided, so I won’t pretend that I can give you the details. Please look into the documentation of `LocaleServiceProvider` and its subclass `DateFormatProvider` (links at the bottom).

### Getting the localized format pattern string for a locale

```
    Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN");
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, loc));
```

Output on my Java 9:

> dd/MM/yy

Please note that I am using `FormatStyle.SHORT`, not `MEDIUM`. In any case I believe that this is the first part of a solution to your problem.

### Possible next-best solutions

The output above is not that far, just using slashes where you wanted dashes/hyphens. You may consider whether your users can live with it. The result on other Java versions may be different, though.

Running your Java program with system property `java.locale.providers` starting with `HOST` will cause Java to use the operating system’s date format *for the default locale only*. First, you may check whether this gives you what you want. Second and maybe more importantly, this allows the user to choose their own date format by configuring their operating system. For example

```
java -Djava.locale.providers=HOST,CLDR,COMPAT YourApp
```

Read more in the documentation of `LocaleServiceProvider`.

On the same Java 9 as before, the output I get for `te-IN` (teluga) locale is the `dd-MM-yy` that you asked for. In many situations the user has chosen a locale beyond out control, but there may also be situations where choosing this locale will solve your problem.

Finally, if you need to support your app on several locales and you — or what counts, your users — are only dissatisfied with the date format for the `en-IN` locale, you may of course hand code an exception for this locale only and hardcode `dd-MM-yy` whenever you get this locale. It’s no beautiful solution, but will work.

### Links

- [`LocaleServiceProvider` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html)
- [`DateFormatProvider` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/spi/DateFormatProvider.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String pattern = dateFormat.toPattern();
```

Here you need to set exact date format which you want. For now in your code its assigning default format `java.text.DateFormat.MEDIUM` which is `d MMM, yyyy`

Comment: I can not use hardcoded date format like 'DD-MM-YY'. Because I will only have access to language code and country code from which I need to retrieve the dateFormat for the country.

Comment: Then you are doing right with Locale, but whatever customization you want like "DD-MM-YY", you need to do it in conditions hardcoded.

Comment: Are you sure about that format? According to `SimpleDateFormat` documentation `DD` provides day in year. I realize that is what OP literally asked for, but it does not seem right. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides the hard-coded `"dd-MM-yy"` you can use the SHORT format instead of MEDIUM:

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                        java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
```

The newer data time classes work similarly and are worth switching to.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will surely work. But`DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat` is not [thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)(refer the synchronization section).

It is recommend to use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    System.out.println("Formatted date: " + dateTimeFormatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
```